# Design pattern to truncate a large object graph

Tags: java, object, graph

Using Java, I have a very large object graph where an object is associated with many other objects each of which is associated with yet many other objects. Most of the time I just need a sub-graph to pass on to a method or send across a network.

Is there a recommended design pattern so I can truncate this large object graph at many points in the graph. One way would be provide NULL as reference at all points of truncation. I'd appreciate any other ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a design pattern (in terms of GoF), but an appropriate graph representation (data structure), which provides algorithms for truncating and other operations on (sub)graphs.
What is your current data structure?

Comment: Object structure consists of many domain objects. Each object is related to one or more other domain objects and such relationships continue down the lines. An example domain could start from an organization and its link down to its people, various properties it owns, products it purchases, sells, etc - a large inter-related class diagram.

Comment: How do you specify a subgraph? Does your subgraph consist of a set of node objects?

Comment: Your use case sounds like a usage of a database, where you can filter a subset with the SQL clause `WHERE`. Maybe a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you could use [Lazy Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).
This strategy is commonly used when mapping object with associations which you do not need right now, and may not need at all. (It is widely used in Hibernate ORM).
When you want to send large objects accross a network you can use Proxy Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build your graph out of Node objects (as you're doing now), and then to truncate the graph, encapsulate it with a Graph object which stores the graph as a member, provides its own interface to run operations on the graph, and internally uses a table of nodes that are to be considered removed from the graph.

The benefit of this approach is that you're not mutating the original graph object itself, and you also don't have to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

[Proxy Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0222-designpatterns.html) is a good design pattern for this kind of problem.

Comment: I can see how a Lazy Factory may help with this problem. I'd like to understand how Proxy pattern would. Could you expand upon your answer with, perhaps, an example?

Comment: An Entity proxy can be created from a common interface which is also implemented by real objects. The primary key for each entity and its proxy is passed to its constructor method. The real entity will have a load method to get the data from the db based on its primary key. The proxy object will use composition to call the real objects load method when the real object is requested, in the lazy loading pattern.